# How to upload the text file using jmeter with json data

Tags: file-upload

I am using jmeter tool.While upload the text file, its shows the message as "Actual File content,its not shown here".Could you tell me the configuration to upload the text file.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload any file in HTTP request. Please refer below snapshot
[image]

Also try to record this call from application. It'll automatically fill this for you